# Use url name to set name of image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I want to do the following:

I've got webpages, called 1.html , 2.html , 3.html etc. Now I have the following code for 1.html:

```
<object width="100%" data="1.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
```

and for 2.html, I would get 2.svg. etc. Now I want to make something like 100 pages like this, and I'm wondering if it is possible to do this automaticly using javascript or jquery ? So something like:

```
<object width="100%" data="[here some script that get the name of htm file].svg" type="image/svg+xml">
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Yes, you can get the name of the page (`window.location`) then split it, extract the name and set the attribute on the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**jQuery**

```
var url = document.location.pathname;
url = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.lastIndexOf("."));
$('object').attr('data', url + '.svg');
```

**Javascript**

```
var url = document.location.pathname;
url = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.lastIndexOf("."));
document.getElementsByTagName('object')[0].setAttribute('data',url + '.svg');
```

Or this:

**PHP**

```
<object data="<?php echo basename(__FILE__, ".htm"); ?>.svg"></object>
```

Comment: I tried this: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Part 1</title>
  <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var id = document.location.pathname.split('.')[0];
    id = id.split('/')[1];
    $('object').attr('data', id + '.svg');
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div><object width="100%"  type="image/svg+xml"></object></div>
 </body>
</html>
but this don't work

Comment: The page is blocking jQuery as insecure.

Comment: Then just do it in javascript. Replace the last line with this: `document.getElementsByTagName("object")[0].setAttribute("src",id + ".svg");`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32191/discussion-between-alex-morrise-and-kasper)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
var currentDoc = document.location.pathname
var currentSVG = currentDoc.match(/\d+\) + ".svg";
```